# Custom comparator for sorting arrays in Liquid or Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid, jekyll-paginator

I am trying to set up a blog in Jekyll. Some (not all) of my posts have `updated_on` variable in its front matter which I use to store the date (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +0530`) it was last updated on.

I wish to display the posts on my index page in the decreasing order of `post.updated_on` if available, otherwise using `post.date`. To make things clear, here is pseudo-code of what I want my sort comparator to work like

```
comp(post a, post b){
    if(a.updated_on) t1 = a.updated_on
    else t1 = a.date

    if(b.updated_on) t2 = b.updated_on
    else t2 = b.date

    return t1>t2
}
```

**How can I achieve this kind of sorting in Liquid/Jekyll?**

One fallback I have thought is to add `updated_on` in every post even if it was never updated since post date. Then I could do something like

```
{% assign sorted_posts = paginator.posts | sort: 'updated_on' | reverse %}
{% for post in sorted_posts %}
  ... some code here ...
{% endfor %}
```

But I don't want to go this way since I will have to manually add `updated_on` to each post where it doesn't already exists.

Comment: I think you should write your own ruby code/plugin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort by a modified variable in Liquid and Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263812/sort-by-a-modified-variable-in-liquid-and-jekyll)